# Angular - autofocus directive for nestled components

Tags: angular, angular-material

I implemented [this](https://www.codementor.io/yomateo/auto-focus-with-angular-7-the-directive-osfcl7rrv) in our product, and for plain input-fields it works pretty well. Sadly only parts of our input architecture uses , mostly we use custom made components

```
<app-edit-value [control]="control"></app-edit-value>
```

Which take a FormControl object and create a slightly nicer input object. Of course that directive won't work here so I added the optional [autofocus] input.

Hidden behind  we have a structure that can handle many differnt types of user input, like check-boxes, lists, texts, numbers and more

```
<mat-form-field *ngIf="control.type = ...">
   <input appAutoFocus="autofocus" ...>
</mat-form-field>
...
```

My idea was to pass down the AppAutofocus directive to the actually focus-able  elements like this, but it doesn't work as intended. Even when I never set [autofucos] elements end up being in focus after the page loaded and I don't have any idea why.

Am I missing something obvious, or is there maybe a more elegant way of doing this?

Comment: Shouldn't this be in brackets like so: `<input [appAutoFocus]="autofocus">`

Comment: @PierreDuc If the value "autofocus" is ment as a string then you can use it without the brackets. But if autofocus is a scoped variable then the [] brackets should be used.

Comment: @FyZ1K of course, it just feels weird to use string on a directive that's specifically designed for autofocus, and the linked autofocus directive in the question expects a boolean

Comment: @PierreDuc Very true.. I'd also expected to have a boolean for such an attribute there but as now it looks like it expects a value of some basic/primitive data type.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to work by adjusting the directive a little bit. Here is the code of the directive :

```
export class AutofocusDirective {
  @Input('autofocus') public isEnabledAutoFocus: boolean;

  public constructor(private el: ElementRef) {}

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    if (this.isEnabledAutoFocus) {
      this.el.nativeElement.focus();
    }
  }
}
```

Then I passed the FormControl from the parent to the Child, and connected it to the input (where the directive is applied on).

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
    <input formControlName="input1" name="one" type="text" placeholder="Input 1" />
    <input formControlName="input2" name="two" type="text" placeholder="Input 2" />
    <app-input-parent [control]="form.get('input3')" isAutoFocus="true"></app-input-parent>
</form>
```

And the child :

```
<input [autofocus]="isAutoFocus" [formControl]="control" placeholder="Input child" type="text">
```

[Here is the link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-3) for testing my code

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

autofocus directive:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appAutofocus]'
})
export class AutofocusDirective {

  @Input() appAutofocus = true;

  constructor(private el: ElementRef) { }

  public ngAfterContentInit() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.appAutofocus) {
        this.el.nativeElement.focus();
      }
    }, 0);
  }

}
```

then on the model of my custom component I added an input to enable autofocus

```
@Input() autofocus=false;
```

the view of the custom component:

```
<div>
    ...
 
    <input [appAutofocus]="autofocus" ...>
</div>
```

and used this way:

```
 <my-component [autofocus]="true">
  </my-component>
```